# If A1 changes, put something into B1 | If A2 changes, put something into B2

Tags: excel, vba

I have rows from 1-100.
I know how to target specific cells and get data from them, but how would I do this when any row from 1 to 100 can be changed?

Say you put anything into Row A3. How would you write "Updated" into row B3 via VBA?
I want this to apply to rows A1-A100.

Thanks

Comment: Look into the Worksheet_Change event.  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel) are links to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, Intersection As Range, Cell As Range

    Set A = Range("A1:A100")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, A)
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Cell In Intersection
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Updated"
        Next Cell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open VBA Editor
2. Double click on the sheet you event take action (sheets appears in the left top box)
3. Select Worksheet on the left box above code box
4. Select change on the right box above code box
5. Paste the code

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

       If Not Intersect(Target, .Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then

           Application.EnableEvents = False
               .Range("B" & Target.Row).Value = "Updated"
           Application.EnableEvents = True
       End If

   End With

   End Sub
   ```